# Website Architecture for Node, Backbone+Marionette, Mongo DB GridFS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, backbone.js, single-page-application, gridfs

I am programming a website with a node.js and mongodb grifs on back-end with backbone and marionette as front end frameworks.

As I am new to creating single page applications (SPA) I may be wrong in any of my assumptions, please correct me wherever I am wrong.

The way I understand the flow of control is:
As soon as the first request to the server is made to **abcxyz.com**, nodejs server serves the base html file via a get request from the **server.js** file. This html file links to the **main.js** file which holds all the backbone+marionette models, collections and views.

As my aim is to write a SPA (single page application), I assume that from here onwards the flow of control remains completely within the **main.js** file as it is the file which handles the url routing (think of #routes for emails in gmail).

Now my question is this: How can I carry data to and from the mongodb gridfs database for each route change in backbone. Putting another way - how does backbone interface with mongo database which can be accessed only in the **server.js** file, and how do I communicate a change of route (hence a change in the data needed for backbone views) from backbone to the node.js server?

I'm sorry for a really long question, feeling very confused :(